# MySQL Insert Select Syntax

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a bulk insert using the following function of MY SQL, Insert Select.

I already searched all over the net and found the same thing yet when I try to implement this in My SQL Workbench the following happens:

```
INSERT INTO `tblpayments` (pk_ID, fk_Room,Rent) 
SELECT T.pk_ID, T.fk_Room, R.Rent
FROM `tbltenants` T
JOIN `tblrooms` R ON T.fk_Room = R.pk_ID
```

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Rent' in 'field list'

I do not know what I am doing wrong here, also I need to add the current date to this insert.

### Current Create Script

```
CREATE TABLE `tblrooms` (
`pk_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_Homes` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Rent` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`Vacent` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`Available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`DateNotVacent` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pk_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### #

```
CREATE TABLE `tbltenants` (
`pk_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_Branch` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fk_Room` int(11) NOT NULL,
`IDNumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Reference` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Surname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Tel` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`StudentNumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`StudentYear` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`ParentGuardian` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`DomiciliumAddress` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`ParentTel` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`ParentEmail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`SponserDepartment` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`SponserContactPerson` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`SponserEmail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`SponserCell` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pk_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### #

```
CREATE TABLE `tblpayments` (
`pk_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fk_Tenant` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fk_Room` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Amount` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`DateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
`Type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pk_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `tblpayments (pk_ID, fk_Room,Rent)` The stuff in the parentheses should be a list of columns in the `tblpayments` table. The error means that `tblpayments` doesn't contain a column named `Rent`

Comment: @bassxzero you should put that as an answer to this question.

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio While I assume bass is correct, it seems this error also triggers when trying to put a value of a different data type into one of the fields, meaning their could be another cause but most likely not. **At OP** Not sure if `all over the net` applies when searching for `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column in 'field list'` gets you several answers on Google and SO addressing the issue.

Comment: *"I already searched all over the net"* -- have you also reached the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)?

Comment: Can you show the structure/schema of your tables? (tblpayments, tbltenants and tblrooms)

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio If it fixes his problem, then I will. I'm just tired of downvotes.

Comment: Check If `tblrooms` table has the column `Rent`.

Comment: i have updated the question, i have read the My SQL Documentation didnt find a example on where to do a bulk insert based on entries of 2 tables. Seems then i can only insert items thats inside the tblpayments columns and not thats being retrieved from the other tables? I have checked now, if i do change the column names to be exacly the same as the copied table will it add those data to the tblpayments table from the other 2 tables?

Comment: I have confirmed that it is the case where Rent was not available in the tblpayments table, you may add your answer so i can mark it as correct. Thanks.